# Java Collector with Closeable resource as accumulator

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Suppose I'm trying to create a collector that aggregates data into a resource that has to be closed after usage. Is there any way to implement something similar to a `finally` block in a `Collector`? In the successful case this could be done in the `finisher` method, but there does not seem to be any method invoked in case of exceptions.

The goal would be to implement an operation like the following in a clean way and without having to collect the stream into an in-memory list first.

```
stream.collect(groupingBy(this::extractFileName, collectToFile()));
```

Comment: so you're thinking of something like `Collector#onError`? If so, there is no such thing, you would have to do that yourself...

Comment: @Eugene Yes, or maybe a way to cleanly attach an `onClose` method the the stream being collected.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I'd like each group to be closed and the exception be propagated. In my example, the accumulator provided by `Collector.supplier()` could implement `Closeable` and should behave like it was invoked in a try-with-resources block.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner any checked exception would have to be wrapped into unchecked ones, like `UncheckedIOException`. But I think the question is more general than file io. Either on successful completion or any exception I'd like to `close` a resource. Looking at some more, I could probably wrap all the collector functions to do this, but there would still be the edge case of any exception inside the stream processing itself. I don't think there are any guarantees that these never throw.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that is actually the very first idea in a comment I had (deleted it, since it seemed too dumb :| ). you *could* wrap every method from the collector indeed, but my doubt is that while some thread caught an exception and some other thread is/will plan to write to the same file. These threads need to communicate somehow, I thought the OP will provide details in how he wants to handle such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I think you could fulfil your requirement would be by means of a close handler supplied to the [`Stream.onClose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-) method. Suppose you have the following class:

```
class CloseHandler implements Runnable {
    List<Runnable> children = new ArrayList<>();

    void add(Runnable ch) { children.add(ch); }

    @Override
    public void run() { children.forEach(Runnable::run); }
}
```

Now, you'd need to use your stream as follows:

```
CloseHandler closeAll = new CloseHandler();
try (Stream<Something> stream = list.stream().onClose(closeAll)) {
    // Now collect
    stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        this::extractFileName, 
        toFile(closeAll)));
}
```

This uses the `try-with-resources` construct, so that the stream is automatically closed either when consumed or if an error occurs. Note that we're passing the `closeAll` close handler to the `Stream.onClose` method.

Here's a sketch of your downstream collector, which will collect/write/send elements to the `Closeable` resource (note that we're also passing the `closeAll` close handler to it):

```
static Collector<Something, ?, Void> toFile(CloseHandler closeAll) {

    class Acc {

        SomeResource resource; // this is your closeable resource

        Acc() {
            try {
                resource = new SomeResource(...); // create closeable resource
                closeAll.add(this::close);        // this::close is a Runnable
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }

        void add(Something elem) {
            try {
                // TODO write/send to closeable resource here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }

        Acc merge(Acc another) {
            // TODO left as an exercise
        }

        // This is the close handler for this particular closeable resource
        private void close() {
            try {
                // Here we close our closeable resource
                if (resource != null) resource.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, a -> null);
}
```

So, this uses a local class (named `Acc`) to wrap the closeable resource, and declares methods to `add` an element of the stream to the closeable resource, and also to `merge` two `Acc` instances in case the stream is parallel (left as an exercise, in case it's worth the effort).

`Collector.of` is used to create a collector based on the `Acc` class' methods, with a finisher that returns `null`, as we don't want to put anything in the map created by `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Finally, there's the `close` method, which closes the wrapped closeable resource in case it has been created.

When the stream is implicitly closed by means of the `try-with-resources` construct, the `CloseHandler.run` method will be automatically executed, and this will in turn execute all the child close handlers previously added when each `Acc` instance was created.

Comment: the `merge` is what mostly stopped me from posting something like this... Unless the OP comes with details about what exactly happens when a ThreadA throws an Exception (in the `merge`) and ThreadB wants to write to the same file, not even sure this is part of the requirement

Comment: *... without having to collect the stream into an in-memory list first* so it seems there is some IO/DB/JMS whatever. If the OP confirm I would gladly upvote btw

Comment: Thanks, the combination of a mutable `onClose` callback, where each accumulator gets registered solves the problem quite nicely. I'm not concerned about parallel processing at the moment, whether a merge operation is possible (and faster than just sequential processing) depends too much on the resource. Actually a followup question would be whether sequential streams are guaranteed to never call the combiner method of a collector.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann that is guaranteed by the spec, check the [`Collector` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have took a look on `Collectors` implementation, you need `CollectorImpl` to create custom collector but its not public. So I implement new one using its copy (last 2 method you might be interested in):

```
public class CollectorUtils<T, A, R> implements Collector<T, A, R> {

    static final Set<Collector.Characteristics> CH_ID = Collections
            .unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));

    private final Supplier<A> supplier;
    private final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator;
    private final BinaryOperator<A> combiner;
    private final Function<A, R> finisher;
    private final Set<Characteristics> characteristics;

    CollectorUtils(Supplier<A> supplier, BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator, BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
            Function<A, R> finisher, Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.combiner = combiner;
        this.finisher = finisher;
        this.characteristics = characteristics;
    }

    CollectorUtils(Supplier<A> supplier, BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator, BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
            Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
        this(supplier, accumulator, combiner, castingIdentity(), characteristics);
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator() {
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<A> supplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<A> combiner() {
        return combiner;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<A, R> finisher() {
        return finisher;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return characteristics;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <I, R> Function<I, R> castingIdentity() {
        return i -> (R) i;
    }

    public static <C extends Collection<File>> Collector<String, ?, C> toFile() {
        return new CollectorUtils<>((Supplier<List<File>>) ArrayList::new, (c, t) -> {
            c.add(toFile(t));
        }, (r1, r2) -> {
            r1.addAll(r2);
            return r1;
        }, CH_ID);
    }

    private static File toFile(String fileName) {
        try (Closeable type = () -> System.out.println("Complete! closing file " + fileName);) {
            // stuff
            System.out.println("Converting " + fileName);

            return new File(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create file");

    }

}
```

Then I call stream as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("x.txt", "y.txt","z.txt").collect(CollectorUtils.toFile());
    }
```

Output:

```
Convertingx.txt
closing filex.txt
Convertingy.txt
closing filey.txt
Convertingz.txt
closing filez.txt
```

Comment: This differs in what I want to achieve, the goal would be to write the contents of the stream to different files, depending on some grouping key. And this requires the `FileOutputStream` to be closed at some point, even on exceptions. BTW, you can use `Collector.of` as a factory method instead of implementing the interface yourself.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann thanks Collector.of really cool didnt know that